# Compile issues, scoping and order of evaluation

Tags: compile, scoping, vector

I have a few questions about compiling functions, which I think are all related to scoping and order of evaluation.

I will illustrate them by a minimal example of the problem I have. I'm sorry for the lengthy question.

The setup code is this,

```
mat = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};

expr = {a^2 - ma + 3 x^3, a mb^2 + 2 b x, mc a - mb ma x^6};
Do[exprIndexed[i] = expr[[i]], {i, 1, 3}]
x = {5, -2};
atest = {1, 2}; btest = {2, 1}; ctest = {0, 0};
```

I have a list of expressions expr, each of which represents a vector.
The first depends only on `a`, `ma` stands for the matrix `mat` times the vector `a`, and `x` is a constant known vector. The second depends on `a` and `b` and the last on `a, b, c`.

I want to write for each of these expressions a compiled code that evaluates them. In particular I want to be able to define these compiled functions inside a do loop, I want them to really fully compile, and I want it to evaluate as much as it can without knowing the variables (`a`, `{a, b}` and `{a, b, c}` respectively).

One attempt is this: 
(NOTE: i'm omitting everywhere the last argument `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, CompilationTarget -> "C"` for brevity)

```
Compile[Evaluate[({#, _Real, 1} &) /@ Take[{a, b, c}, i]],
  ma = mat.a; 
  If[i > 1, mb = mat.b]; 
  If[i > 2, dc = mat.c];
  exprIndexed[i],
  {{exprIndexed[i], _Real, 1}, {ma, _Real, 1}, {mb, _Real,1}, {mat, _Real, 2}}]
```

(A not so important question I have here is: when it is and when it's not necessary to include these type specifications at the end)

Plugging in by hand `i = 1`, and copying for `i = 2`, etc., this code works.

Wrapping it in a `Do`, e.g.

```
Do[comp[i]= (expr above)]
```

does not work. *Mathematica* gives

> CompiledFunction::cfse: Compiled expression {373. +a^2,-25.+a^2} should be a machine-size integer. >>

However, writing

```
loopCode[i_] := (code above)
Do[comp[i] = loopCode[i]]
```

does work. I wonder why this is so?

Although the code works, it does not compile completely (I checked this by doing `Export["test.c", comp[1]]`). The reason is that the assignments set the global value of e.g. da, so must talk to *Mathematica*.

This can be fixed by changing the body of the compile to

```
Module[{ma = mat.a},
exprIndexed[i]]
```

Now it works and compiles, but it cannot be defined in a loop.

Explicitly, I tried,

```
loopComp[i_] := 
  Compile[Evaluate[({#, _Real, 1} &) /@ Take[{a, b, c}, i]],
    Module[{da = mat.a}, exprIndexed[i]],
      {{exprIndexed[i], _Real, 1}, {da, _Real, 1}, {db, _Real, 1}, {mat, _Real, 2}}]

Do[comp[i] = loopComp[i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

I haven't found a way to automate the assignment of `ma`, `mb` and `mc`, i.e. to get `Module[{ma=mat.a},...]` for `i=1`, `Module[{ma=mat.a, mb=mat.b},...}]` for `i=2` etc.,
so `comp[2]` and `comp[3]` shouldn't work, but at least `comp[1]` should, but it does not.

```
comp[1][atest]
```

gives the error

> CompiledFunction::cfte: Compiled expression da should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >>

and the output

> ```
> {376 - da, -20 - da}
> ```

I think the issue is in the scoping of `Do`, `Module` and `Compile`, but I don't know how to fix it.

The final issue is this. Even in the working versions of this code (just by explicitly copy-pasting and inserting the `i = 1, 2, 3` ) each time it runs everything is computed, i.e. the `x^6` is not computed by compile once and for all, but every time the code is run.

Note that if `x` is defined before expr is defined, then this does not happen, but then there is another problem in that i.e. `x + a` will become `{5 + a, -2 + a}` and when `a` is plugged in we get a matrix instead of a vector.
So I want to evaluate as much as possible, while still getting a vector as output.

Comment: If I copy your code as given, then trying to compile the very first function fails with an error "Sequence specification...". Can you please confirm that you have **all** the code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes that's right, what I meant was that if you copy the first code, and then by hand replace the i with 1 or 2 or 3, then it does work, but if you do these replacements in a loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: I found a way to do it in a loop just now. If in the last loopComp you replace Module[{da=mat.a},exprIndexed[i]] with Module[{da=mat.a,expr=exprIndexed[i]},expr], it works. I would still like to understand why though.