# Compile a function with undetermined number of variables

Tags: compile

I have been wrapping my head about a question it may look simple to you. I want compile a function that depends on a number of undetermined variables as,

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}, {w,_Real},...}, Evaluate[f(x,y,z,w,..,)], 
 RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
 Parallelization -> True]
```

Where {x,y,z,...} can be as long as needed. I have tried the simple exercise of doing,

```
var={x,y,z}
list=Table[{var[[i]], _Re},{i,Length@var}];
Compile[list, Evaluate[f(x,y,z,w,..,)], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True]
```

but it does not seem to work since _Re needs to be symbolic? (I am asking but I do not know).

Thanks for your comprehension!

UPDATE:

I found a solution thanks to: [Evaluating arguments of module (inside compile)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60632/evaluating-arguments-of-module-inside-compile?rq=1)

This is what it worked for me:

```
Compile[Evaluate@({#, _Real} & /@ var), Evaluate[f(x,y,z,w,..,)], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", Parallelization -> True]
```

Comment: Why not just have your compiled function accept a list of reals?

Comment: Hi J.M. thanks for replying. I am not sure I understand what you mean. Are you asking to pass to compile a list of reals instead of a function? If this is the case, this does not work for me since the list is huge and I have to pass it many times.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what [@JM was suggesting](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221640/compile-a-function-with-undetermined-number-of-variables#comment564165_221640):

```
cfun = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Sin[list]];
```

In other words, define your function to take a rank-1 tensor (i.e. a list) of reals; **you do not need to specify the length beforehand**! Then, just evaluate whatever you need on that `list`. For instance, here are two examples with lists of different lenghts:

```
cfun[Range[10000]]
(* {0.841471, 0.909297, 0.14112, -0.756802, ..., 0.992973, 0.636087, -0.305614}*)

cfun[Range[3]]
(* {0.841471, 0.909297, 0.14112} *)
```

Comment: Once again, thanks for following through!